# Search by results of previous search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

It is possible to make a search by the results of another search?. For example:

```json
// index: A
{ "ID": 1, "status": "done" }
{ "ID": 2, "status": "processing" }
{ "ID": 3, "status": "done" }
{ "ID": 4, "status": "done" }

// index: B
{ "ID": 1, "user": 1, "value": 10 }
{ "ID": 1, "user": 2, "value": 3 }
{ "ID": 2, "user": 1,"value": 1 }
{ "ID": 3, "user": 1, "value": 3 }
{ "ID": 4, "user": 1, "value": 7 }
```

Q1: Search in index "A" `status == "done"` and return the ID

```
RES: 1,3,4
```

Q2: From the results in Q1 search `value > 5` and return the ID

```
RES: 1,4
```

My current solution is use two queries and download the results of "Q1" and make a second search in "Q2" but is very complicated because have 30k of results.

Comment: Elasticseachc is not a relational database, what are want to do is (as far as I know) not doable.
But would it be possible to merge the 2 index in 1 ? (I am trying to reframe your problem)

Comment: I create in kibana index: "A,B" and I cant make a serch in bot index. So if I can take the results of a query and make another query in whole index (not the results)

Answer (score 0):

the problem to me seems to be more of a traditional union of filters in 2 indexes sort of a join , what we have in relational databases , not sure of the exact solution but recently had used a plug-in for the joins -> https://siren.io/siren-federate-20-0-introducing-a-scalable-inner-join-for-elasticsearch/ this might help